# Rails on iOS - action "show" could not be found on :method => :delete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile-safari

I have a Rails application that has a mobile view for iOS users.

All links seem to be working, except those that have posts tied to the rails :delete method. An example link_to:

```
<%= link_to list_task_path(t.list, t), :method => :delete do %>
      <%= image_tag "white_minus.png", :id => "complete_task", :class => "#{important_class?(t)} icon", :title => "Complete Task", :alt => "Complete Task" %>
      <% end %>
```

When this link is pressed on mobile safari, the following error is returned: *The action 'show' could not be found...*

I tried turning the link into an ajax link to see if that correct the problem, no cigar:

```
$(function() {
  $("#complete_task a").click(function() {
    $.post(this.href, { _method: 'delete' }, null, "script");
    return false;
  });  
});
```

I think the issue is related to javascript that I'm using, though admittedly don't understand to the fullest, to stop links from opening up in mobile safari if the website has been added to the users homescreen. It's copy pasta on my part from another question on here:

```
// open links in app and not safari

var iWebkit;if(!iWebkit){iWebkit=window.onload=function(){function fullscreen(){var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){if(a[i].className.match("noeffect")){}else{a[i].onclick=function(){window.location=this.getAttribute("href");return false}}}}function hideURLbar(){window.scrollTo(0,0.9)}iWebkit.init=function(){fullscreen();hideURLbar()};iWebkit.init()}}
```

Removing this javascript allows me to execute deletes, but all other links are opened externally like they're a _blank target.

I was wondering if anyone else had been in a similar situation and were able to correct destroy links on Rails 3 running in mobile safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this script correctly than you should add the class `noeffect`to the link. This prevents the default behaviour of the script, which is to set window.location to the anchor's href

Comment: You are a god among men. Thank you so much :)